# Report/Dashboard to track historical changes in opportunity stage

Tags: reporting, dashboard, history-tracking, opportunity-pipelines

I am after best practices/examples of building out:

A dashboard view (graph) to present weekly/monthly changes in pipeline stages. This is to be used at deal review meeting so we can track how teams are moving up/down the funnel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Opportunity Stage History related list, and there's the Opportunity Stage History canned report, which you can customize and make into dashboard components. If you need more granular data, such as weekly snapshots, you can build [Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_about_analytic_snap.htm&type=5), basically, you create a custom object to hold your data, then a Reporting Snapshot to periodically capture data into the custom object, which you can then report on and include in Dashboards.